# Bootstrap 3 accordion - expand collapse icons beside panel title

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I want this simple Bootstrap 3 accordion:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

to have an plus icon when in closed and a minus icon when in hover and active. 
My css:

```
.panel-title a {
     background: url('plus.png') no-repeat 100% 50% ;
     padding-right:20px;}
.panel-title a:hover{
   background: url('minus.png') no-repeat 100% 50% ; }
.panel-title a:active {
  background: url('minus.png') no-repeat 100% 50% ; }
```

So far is working except the active state. Can you help me to make it work?
Thank you

Comment: Did you try `focus` instead of `active`?

Comment: Yes but when you click again to close remains the minus icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly, the `:active` state only occurs while the link is actually be clicked. `:active` has nothing to do with the state of the collapse.

To get this to work, I would change your CSS to something like this:

```
.panel-title a {
   background: url('plus.png') no-repeat 100% 50% ;
   padding-right:20px;}
.panel-title a:hover{
   background: url('minus.png') no-repeat 100% 50% ; }
.panel-title a.active {
  background: url('minus.png') no-repeat 100% 50% ; }
```

Note that instead of using the `:active` pseudo, we are actually going to use a class called `.active`.

Now, just toggle the class on and off via javascript. There are a couple of ways to do this, but the most straight forward would be to attach a listener to the existing `a` tag, like so:

```
$('[data-toggle]').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

So in summary, change `:active` to `.active` in your css, and add three lines of javascript.

See http://www.bootply.com/130209 for a working example.

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for your answer but did not work. Script did not make any difference.

Comment: Sorry about that, completely wrong javascript. Updated answer with correct javascript and link to working example.

Comment: Thank you Sean, I see that works there but not in my environment. I use it inside a Joomla module in a T3 bs3 template, the script is in the page source but it is not make the trick to give the .active state. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Sean can you please take a look here [link](http://goo.gl/vxR5Sh) to see why your solution is not working? I did all the above of your working example without success. Thank you

Comment: That was helpful. Looks like you are loading jQuery noconflict. So in the javascript I provided, replace `$` with `jQuery` and see if that helps.

Comment: It is working perfect with one panel, to make it complete, it is best to make it work with more panels. 
If you have time check it here [link](http://goo.gl/WD1cVi)
In all cases your answer was right for me. 
Thanks again